# React Modal Component Using Functional Hooks

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-props

I am working on an app that requires a modal component, this component is currently encompassed with three props that are passed to callback three different modals in the app structure. What I need to achieve is when a button is clicked for the specific modal, add a unique class to the modal wrapper that will identify each modal when clicked, thus manipulating the css with selectors for those modals.

see below:

```
const NWmodal = (props) => {
return (
<Modal>
  <Modalmain data-modal-type="this should pass in a unique id to its modal once button is clicked">
      <div>
        {props.ejectModal}
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.timeModal}
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.leaveModal}
      </div>
    <Close>
      x
    </Close>
  </Modalmain>
</Modal>
);
}
  <NWmodal
    id="timeModal"
    timeModal={<NWtimeModal/>} (callback for timemodal component)
  />
  <NWmodal
    id="leaveModal"
    leaveModal={<NWleaveModal/>} (callback for leavemodal component)
  />
  <NWmodal
    id="ejectModal"
    leaveModal={<NWejectModal/>} (callback for ejectmodal component)
  />

function Nav() {
return (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        data-modal="timeModal"
        onClick={event}>
         Time Modal
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        data-modal="leaveModal"
        onClick={event}>
         Leave Modal
      </button>
     </li>
     <li>
      <button
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        data-modal="ejectModal"
        onClick={event}>
         Eject Modal
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

);
}

Comment: Could you please format code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer: I'm still learning this React thing, but the approach I would likely take...

The ***useRef*** hook can be used to create variables, which may then in turn be associated with your modals as a reference. eg:

```
const ejectModalRef = useRef()

<NWmodal id="ejectModal" ref={ejectModalRef} />
```

The node will be accessible in the *onClick* JS code as 'ejectModalRef.current'.

(Don't forget to import ***useRef*** eg.: `import React, { useRef } from "react";`

HTH